# How do I get the slider to be shorter in length and appear on the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Right now I have a slider that goes from 0 to 100. However, it appears at the top of the page and takes up the entire width of the page. I want to make the slider shorter in length and be centered on the page. Thank you!

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/codebeginner1/vd5uLqgz/2/

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS to style it:

```js
$( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handle.text( ui.value );
      }
    });
  } );
```

```css
#custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  

  /* Set the slider width to whatever you want and then
     cause the div to be centered by setting both margins to auto. */
  #slider { width:200px; margin:auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Custom handle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```